# Samsung Gear VR - open menu item from Gear VR tap click

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, oculus, virtual-reality, gear-vr

I create menu (canvas ui) with Render mode work space , it consist from  two buttons

> Start
>
> Quit

I try open start with Gear taps , but it dosent work

```
sing UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class LoadOnClick : MonoBehaviour {

    public void LoadScene(int Level){
        if (Input.GetButtonDown (0)) {
            Application.LoadLevel (Level);
        }

    }
}
```

***Notice it work with me when I goes in play mode , with mouse click***

sugguestion should I make tag to button

what I want make sure I understand well , **when On CLick fired** to run my script

> can I specify input here

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have yet to try this myself but according to [the unity docs](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButtonDown.html) you should replace:

```
Input.GetButtonDown(0)
```

with

```
Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)
```

-EDIT-
Also a suggestion [here](https://forums.oculus.com/viewtopic.php?t=20109) to use:

```
Input.GetButtonDown("Mouse 0")
```

-Further edit-
I did a quick test and `Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)` was the only variant of the three that registered a click so I would use that.

This example project displays and resets a timer on tapping the pad:

```
public Text timerText;
public float timeLeft;

void Start ()
{
    timeLeft = 5;
}

void Update()
{
    timeLeft -= Time.deltaTime;
    timerText.text = timeLeft.ToString ();

    if(timeLeft < 0)
    {
        GameOver();
    }
}

void GameOver()
{
    timerText.text = "-- --";
    // restart on tap
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) 
    {
        Start ();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for you answer , but I update my question , I need to know when on click fire ? which input takes